# Perl script doesn't see modules .pm

Tags: perl

I have a perl scripts (proj_perl.pl , and proj_perl_client.pl) ,  I also created module proj_library.pm. My .pm looks:

```
package proj_library;
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(help);


sub help{#my code}
1;
```

In my .pl scripts I invoke sub help and it looks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use IO::Socket;
use JSON;
use proj_library qw(help); #LOOK HERE!
```

Then I invoke help somewhere in the code.
The problem is when I wan to run my script: ./pro_perl.pl  Terminal shows me sth like this:

```
Can't locate proj_library.pm in @INC (you may need to install the proj_library module) (@INC 
contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 
/usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at 
./proj_perl.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./proj_perl.pl line 8.
```

So I don;t know what is going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that your pm is in your @INC? If you need to load a custom PM folder, check [perldoc.perl.org/lib](https://perldoc.perl.org/lib)

use as:

```
use lib "."
```

or

```
use lib "my_libs/"
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't use either of those. You assume the current work directory is the script's directory, which is a really bad assumption

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to tell Perl to search in the script's directory:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```